# Hibernate Issue when importing 270000 rows of data

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have 270,000 rows of data for import, these data will be imported to 7 joined tables. with hibernate , after 10,000 imports, operation continues slowly and after about 50,000 imports, speed is 1 import per second!

I'm using postgresql 9.6 and hibernate4 with spring in web application.

how can I handle or solve this problem?

Comment: I had a similar situation, we just limited the results and used an infinite scroll for UI. Also since you mention hibernate most teams I know use caching like EHCache or Redis. Also check out views [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html) GL

Comment: Try to use Stateless Session - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174271/using-statelesssession-for-batch-processing

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you use pgAdmin or access PostgreSQL command-line interface?

I have been working with tons of files with more than 7 million rows each one and importing is a pretty easy and fast task.